# R. Why does my function ignore 1 (and correctly work with any numbers)?

Tags: r, function

The function need count numbers and how often the use (input - vector, output - matrix). (I know, how I can do it more easy, but I want understand the error).
Problems is that function ignore 1 in vectors.

```
count_elements <- function(x) {

y <- sort(x)
m <- matrix(, nrow = 2, ncol = length(unique(x)))
a <- 1
for (i in 1:length(sort(x))) {
  if(is.element(y[i], m))  {
  } else { 
    (m[1, a] <- y[i]) & (m[2, a] <- sum(y == y[i])) & (a <- a+1) }
  } 
m
}
```

Examples inputs and outputs:

Without 1 in a vector

```
x <- c(2:10, 2, 3:7, -1)
count_elements(x)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]   -1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
#[2,]    1    2    2    2    2    2    2    1    1     1`
```

With 1 in a vector

```
x <- c(0:10, 2, 3:7, -1)
count_elements(x)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
#[1,]   -1    0    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     9    10    NA
#[2,]    1    1    2    2    2    2    2    2    1     1     1    NA
```

Thank you and sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 5):

The issue is with your logical `if` test.  You ask "is `y[i]` an element of `m`?"  This checks both the first and second row of `m`.  So using your second example `x`, when you've gone through the loop twice, `m` looks like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,]   -1    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA
[2,]    1    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA
```

and on the next iteration of the loop, the `if` is TRUE because there is a 1 in the second row. Note that you just happened to find the error with a 1, but the same error could occur with any positive number. For example, if `x = c(1, 1, 2, 3)` you would get the error with the 2 because you've found two 1s by the time you get to the 2 in the loop.

I think the simplest fix is to change the `if` statement to this:

```
if(is.element(y[i], m[1,]))
```

---

A few other coding thoughts for what they're worth:

- `length(sort(x))` is the same as `length(x)`.  Not sure why you need the "sort"
- Nothing happens if the `if` statement evaluates to TRUE, so it seems like there's no need for any if/else business
- I've never seen this parentheses-ampersand coding style, e.g.: `() & () & ()`.  Newlines or semi-colons are the typical way to separate commands in R
- And even though you mention that you're intentionally doing this the hard way, it's worth noting that `table(x)` will do exactly the same thing, in a lot less time and with fewer errors :)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing your assignments inside a `logical` expression. The `&` operator means `AND`, it is not generally used to bind expressions together like you are doing.

You can simplify your code by indexing only over the unique elements of `x`. This eliminates `a` and the need to check whether or not you've included an element, which is where your problem is coming from.

```
count_elements_new <- function(x) {

  y <- sort(x)
  u <- unique(y)
  m <- matrix(, nrow = 2, ncol = length(u))
  for (i in 1:length(u)) {
    m[1, i] <- u[i]
    m[2, i] <- sum(y == u[i])
  }
  m
}
```

(This eliminates the `if()`, but you could also use a `!` in your `if()` statement and delete `else`, like this: `if(!is.element(y[i], m))`)